# Can't find devices with web-bluetooth with Chrome on Laptop

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I'm experimenting with scanning for ble devices with the web-bluetooth-functionality. When using my mobile device, I'm able to find devices near me, but the same site doesn't work on my laptop. I'm using the sample from github:

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/scan.html?allAdvertisements=true

Bluetooth is running on my laptop and I already checked with the `chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices`, which lists devices near my laptop.

Am I missing something or does anyone else have an idea?

Comment: What version of Chrome and operating system are you running on your laptop?

Comment: @ReillyGrant Windows 10 and Chrome 84.0.4147.105

Comment: Try again on Chrome 85.0.4161.0 or later. Scanning was not fully implemented on Windows until that version.

Comment: @ReillyGrant Hmm, even on the latest beta release it doesn't find devices